# EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL Blt doesn't do anything

Tags: uefi

I was trying to display something on screen using UEFI.

Almost PC which had UEFI drawed well with framebuffer.
But one PC had older UEFI and I had to draw using Blt function in EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL.(Probably because that PC's IGP had no UEFI module..)

But whenever I try it, it doesn't do anything.
I tried same thing in VMware, but it doesn't work either.

This is what I have tried.

```
EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL p;
p.Red = 255;
p.Green = 0;
p.Blue = 0;
EFI_STATUS status = prot->Blt(prot, &p, EfiBltVideoFill, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 0);
```

NOTE: prot is instance of EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL.

I googled and I couldn't find any problem with arguments and I checked status variable and it said EFI_SUCCESS.

That thing draws red pixel to entire screen, right?
But it didn't draw anything on screen.

I tried this after drawing something on framebuffer.(And of course, it worked pretty well on VMware)
But I couldn't see any change on screen. Not even a black screen or something else. What I could see is what I had draw using framebuffer.

Am I doing something wrong?

Of course, I haven't used ExitBootServices() yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try [getting all protocol handles](https://github.com/LongSoft/CrScreenshotDxe/blob/9a92fe6d641d0b3bf973774d92adaabf4364dfa2/CrScreenshotDxe.c#L111), not just one, because some systems have multiple instances of GOP, and the first one can be a black screen (second monitor which is not connected now, etc.) you are trying to write to.